# Passing a form to a directive: undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've got this code (updated)

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="form" novalidate>
      <directive form="form.test" required
      ><input type="text" ng-model="text" name="test" required="true" /></directive>
      <button ng-click="click()">Click me</button>
    </form>
  </body>
```

Javascript

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.click = function(){
    console.log('click');
  }
});

app.directive('directive', function() {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      form: '=',
    },
    template: '<div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transcludeFn) {
      var inputDiv = angular.element('<div>')
      transcludeFn(scope, function(clone){
        inputDiv.append(clone);
      })
      element.append(inputDiv);
      scope.$watch(function(){
        return scope.form.$error;
      }, function(newValue){
          console.log('newValue', newValue);
      }, true)
    }
  }
});
```

Every time I click on to the button I get an error of form being undefined.
Try it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/pl76wo4AJiGH0m7b5NQd?p=preview

Comment: `return scope.form[scope.toWatch].$error;` is producing an error

Comment: I solved it: I updated the plunk to reflect the problem. If you move the element.append(inputDiv) function call into the transclude function, it somehow starts working.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 things that could be changed, first I'd add an `ng-model` attribute to the text input and an `ng-required` attribute so the error will be tracked with the model's controller

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test" ng-required="true" />
```

next you need to include the objectEquality parameter on the $watch, so it will watch for changes on the $error object properties

```
scope.$watch(function(scope) {
  return scope.form[scope.toWatch].$error;
}, function(newValue) {
  // newValue will be the $error object from the input
}, true); // notice the last true value here, that's the objectEquality parameter
```

here's an updated plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/LnGhWgZF5ZbnqRUxh4gP?p=preview

Comment: Oh, so without ng-model, form stays undefined? But I have an ng-model in my real application.

Comment: Without ng-model you're not going to get that built-in angular error checking on the input because the input will not have a model controller.